# Deleting a string using strrep

Tags: string, matlab

I am new to MATLAB scripting. I have a string to be deleted, the string comes from an array structured file. The string to be deleted is different in every loop. CanI store that changing string in a variable and delete that string using the variable and `strrep`? For example:

```
%% string i want to delete is "is_count_del=auto;"
delstrng=is_count_del_auto;
%%filetext is the name of the file from which is_count_del=auto; is to be deleted
r=strrep(filetext,'delstrng','');
```

I guess I am not using `strrep` correctly. How can the desired outcome be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you could:

```
% open file to be filtered and output file
fin = fopen('file-to-be-filtered.txt');
fout = fopen('output-file.txt');

% for every line of a file-to-be-filtered ...
tline = fgets(fin);
while ischar(tline)
    % ... filter for all possible patterns        
    for delstring % -> delstring iterates over all patterns
        tline = strrep(tline, delstrng, '');
    end

    % save filtered line to file
    fprintf(fout, tline);

    % get next line
    tline = fgets(fin);
end
```

Comment: I cant modify the variable stored in delstrng. it constantly changes.strrep will not delete what string delstrng contains?

Comment: `filetext` should also be string (not file) for this to work. There is no straight-forward way for filtering lines of a file in Matlab (AFAIK); you should read - filter - output. If you would like to filter lines of a file to create another file easily, then maybe you should consider `sed`, `awk` or some other standard Unix utility.

Comment: thank you. if i use r = strrep(strrep, delstrng, ''); will it delete the string contained in the variable delstrng for me?

Comment: @learningMatlab Sorry, I've corrected that line. It was wrong before. Every line of the file is checked for all available patterns and pattern is erased from that line (if it is found). `tline = strrep(tline, delstrng, '');` deletes `delstrng` from `tline`.

Answer (score 1):

[`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) can be applied on cell arrays, so this makes your work really easy:

```
% # Read input file
C = textread('input.txt', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');

% # Remove target string
C = strrep(C, 'is_count_del=auto', '');

% # Write output file
fid = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
for ii = 1:numel(C)
    fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n', C{ii});
end
fclose(fid)
```